# XML asmx annotation not validating for size and requireds

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, asmx

I´m creating a SOAP webservice. My request XML something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Inserir>
         <tem:dados>
            <tem:NroEmpresa>aaaa</tem:NroEmpresa>
            <tem:NomeCliente>dfdsfdsfsdfdsfdsfd</tem:NomeCliente>
         </tem:dados>
      </tem:Inserir>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My XML object is this:

```
public class NoContaDigital
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
    [StringLength(2,ErrorMessage="Tamanho do campo excede limite."),Required]
    public string NroEmpresa { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(string),IsNullable =false)]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Tamanho do campo excede limite."), Required]
}
```

The StringLength with limit of 2 is not being validated not even if I send an empty value (it´s required).

Do I need to implement any class to validate it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
public class NoContaDigital
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(2,ErrorMessage="Tamanho do campo excede limite.")]
    public string NroEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

It could be the order of data annotations.